# Its a way to cover the bar on the top or remove it?

Tags: java, android

Hello everyone i have a question can i remove this [bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc4ZN.png) or cover it?
its anoying when i go back in the app it shows the bar, when i open the [app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD91z.png) then its normal.Can someone help me?

I searched around of the internet and i cant find any question about it to remove the tiny bar on the top.
When you can help me please write it down.

Here is the manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.minecraft_pc.test">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try do it programmatically:

```
    // as the doc page says, this is a solution for Android > 4.1
    View view= getWindow().getDecorView();
    int flagOption = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(flagOption);
```

You can check the [relative doc page](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html).

Comment: i figured it out :D

Comment: are you using the action bar? can you paste the theme that you apply yo the activity? @style/FullScreenTheme?